# PostgreSQL how to convert rows to colums

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have a table like this in my postgres BD:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(id,type,date,value) AS
SELECT *
FROM ( VALUES
  (11::smallint,'A','2016-06-06 19:00:00'::timestamp,81),
  (11,'A','2016-06-06 20:00:00',70),
  (11,'A','2016-06-06 21:00:00',35),
  (11,'B','2016-06-06 19:00:00',2),
  (11,'B','2016-06-06 20:00:00',0),
  (11,'B','2016-06-06 21:00:00',0)
) as f;
```

Here is the data,

```
 id | type |        date         | value
----+------+---------------------+------
 11 | A    | 2016-06-06 19:00:00 |    81
 11 | A    | 2016-06-06 20:00:00 |    70
 11 | A    | 2016-06-06 21:00:00 |    35
 11 | B    | 2016-06-06 19:00:00 |     2
 11 | B    | 2016-06-06 20:00:00 |     0
 11 | B    | 2016-06-06 21:00:00 |     0
```

And this is the result that i want to get:

```
 ID           DATE            A   B
-----|----------------------|----|---
 11  | 2016-06-06 19:00:000 | 81 | 2
 11  | 2016-06-06 20:00:000 | 70 | 0
 11  | 2016-06-06 21:00:000 | 35 | 0
```

Any one knows what is the query that i have to make to get this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT t.id,t.date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.type = 'A' THEN t.value END) as a_col,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.type = 'B' THEN t.value END) as b_col
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.id,t.date
```

Comment: Thanks @sagi , it works!!! but the problem is that I have a lot of types and its very difficult for me to make the query with all of them.

Comment: Then you should use `Pivot` , but to tell you the truth , if its not that many, (20 or so) I prefer to use this version .

Comment: they are like 800 types...its better to use pivot in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Sagi's solution is good , to use a lot of types You can create a request that generates the request of sagi :

```
 select $$SELECT t.id,t.date,$$
       ||string_agg(distinct $$MAX(CASE WHEN t.type = '$$||"type"||$$' THEN t.value END) as $$||"type"||$$_col$$,',')
       ||$$ FROM YourTable t GROUP BY t.id,t.date$$ 
   from YourTable
```

Comment: Hi @Rémy Baron I use your code combined with sagis code and the data output gives me a result with a lot of SELECT queries:

Comment: no just use my code , that generates one query based on sagi's query. Execute this generated query and you have your result

Comment: Im trying it but the console result is a text column with tuis result inside:

Comment: `"SELECT t.id,t.date,MAX(CASE WHEN t.type= '486' THEN t.value  END) as 486_col,MAX(CASE WHEN t.type= '487' THEN t.value END) as 487_col,MAX(CASE WHEN t.type= '488' THEN t.value END) as 488_col,MAX(CASE WHEN t.type= '489'  (...)"`

Comment: yes , it's your generated query now you can get this result and execute it as an new sql query